# MPlayer libavformat/tls_securetransport.c fatal error: Security/Security.h: No such file or directory

Tags: mplayer

I am trying to compile MPlayer with `./configure --enable-gui` from `mplayer-checkout-2015-05-07` on openSUSE 13.2 (Harlequin) (x86_64).

I get the following error:

```
libavformat/tls_securetransport.c:35:31: fatal error: \
Security/Security.h: No such file or directory #include <Security/Security.h>
```

This is a new one to me, I am used to coming up the the right devel packages but Yast is no help. I have no Security directory anywhere on my system.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on Ubuntu 15.04 (x86_64). Solved using updated Mplayer sources via svn checkout and letting ./configure download a new git instance of ffmpeg.
Bye!

Comment: What? I didn't get you.